# Open/close MdDialog inside angular2 services

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have service and error-handler service, when I tried to invoke the dialog box code, it gives an error.

```
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { HeaderDialog } from '../dialog-boxes.component';

export class MyService {
dialogRef: MdDialogRef<any>;
constructor(private dialog: MdDialog) {}
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(HeaderDialog, {
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
});

this.dialogRef.componentInstance.message = 'Hello';
this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    if (result) {}
    this.dialogRef = null;
});
}
```

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: Invalid providers for "HeaderDialog" - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [EConfig, Constants, ?undefined?, ...]

Comment: Only instances of provider allowed but you have a non-provider instance.

Comment: So how can I implement mdDialog inside service? Thanks for reply.

Comment: There's no any applicable way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should post your component HeaderDialog, in this component you have the problem.

Comment: But I want to use HeaderDialog inside service. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I explain bad, I would said you need to post here the HeaderDialog code, to see were is the problem. Because the constructor of this component is where it is failing